# Validate 2 fields should be the same value without one of them has _confirmation in its name in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have debit field and debit field

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="debit" value="{{ isset($expense->debit) ? $expense->debit : old('debit')}}">
```

and

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="credit" value="{{ isset($expense->credit) ? $expense->credit: old('credit')}}">
```

i need to make sure the values are equal when submit the form.

i know I can do that if name them like this:

debit and debit_confirmation and in rule array

```
return Validator::make($data, [
        'debit' => 'required|confirmed',
    ]);
```

but I don't want to change their names.

any build-in validation in laravel 5 do that.

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-same

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the `same` validation rule to match the fields you want.

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    'debit' => 'required|same:credit',
]);
```

You could take a look at the [laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-same) for more information about validation rules

Answer (score 5):

Among many validators that **Laravel** offers there is one you're looking for: **same**. In order to validate if values of 2 different fields (field1, field2) match, you need to define the following rules

```
 $rules = [
  'field1' => 'same:field2'
];
```

You can see a list of all available validation rules here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#available-validation-rules